# Unwanted string with Json inserted from Azure Queue for Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am inserting a message in the Azure queue as Json String as shown below

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

And on the insert in queue, I should receive mail. I am expecting the mails content to be json string but I am receiving the content of mail as shown below

@ string 3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/� {"FirstName":"Vikram"}

Now what is this extra strings at the beginning "@ string 3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/� " in the content and how to remove it.

The work flow for the Logic app is as shown in the figure below for reference
[image]

Comment: Did you try using @json? You can refer to logic app WDL functions here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt643789.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Azure Function to reformat the string to a json string as described here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34750.integrating-service-bus-stack-with-logic-apps-and-azure-functions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Utilize this method upon reading incoming **BrokeredMessage**

```
message.GetBody<string>();
```